# How to POST objects by id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I’m adding objects to my app in NodeJS

**queries.js**

```
const addSong = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
  const { name, link, index, album_id } = request.body;

    for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
      pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (name, link, index, album_id) 
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (index) DO NOTHING RETURNING 
        *', [request.body[i].name, request.body[i].link, 
         request.body[i].index, request.body[i].album_id], (error, 
       results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log(`songs added with album_id: ${album_id}`);
       }
      })
     }
    }
```

**index.js**

```
const app = express();
const db = require('./queries');
app.post('/albums/:id/songs', db.addSong);
```

My problem is that the conflict (unique index value) in my POST request is being added to each object but I only want it to run on each individual object by album_id so that each page acts different and I can add objects with the same index if the album_id is different because in componentDidMount in my ReactJS app I’m fetching songs on a GET request by album_id `WHERE album_id = request.params.id`

Comment: I'm having a tough time understanding what the current behavior vs. the desired behavior is. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish and then explain what is actually happening?

Comment: @bmceldowney in my react app I'm display data on my pages by album_id but in my POST request I'm adding objects and the constraint(unique index value) is being run on all objects but I want it on each object by album_id so each page can act different

Comment: Please post sample data - as text NO images - and the expected results of that data. You may want to review [ask].